# cURL falha ao enviar array

Tags: php, api, libcurl

Bom estou com um pequeno problema ao enviar os dados via cURL, quando envios os dados para a API me retorna que há um dos campos que não é uma array: `{"errors":["items deveria ser um Array"]}`

Código:

```
$user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$pass = '';
$data = array(
        "email" => "Baralho@gmail.com",
        "due_date" => "2018-10-08",
        "items" => array(
                "description"=>"carro",
                "quantity"=> 1,
                "price_cents"=>150000
                ),
        "payer"=>array(
                "cpf_cnpj"=>"644.620.920-74",
                "name"=>"Jeison",
                "phone_prefix"=>"31",
                "phone"=>"991872520",
                "address"=>array(
                        "zip_code"=>"30520240",
                        "number"=>"109",
                        "street"=>"blenda"
                        )
                 )        
        );
$data_string=json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.iugu.com/v1/invoices/' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( $user . ':' . $pass ) ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$return=curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf8");`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Segundo o manual](https://dev.iugu.com/reference#criar-fatura), o problema ocorre, pois, você está enviando **apenas um item** à API. O correto seria enviar um **array de itens**, da seguinte forma:

```
//demais itens omitidos
$data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "description"=>"carro",
            "quantity"=> 1,
            "price_cents"=>150000
        )
    )
);
```

Ou simplificado:

```
//demais itens omitidos
$data = array(
    "items" => [
        [
            "description"=>"carro",
            "quantity"=> 1,
            "price_cents"=>150000
        ]
    ]
);
```

O que ocorre é o seguinte: quando um array associativo é convertido para `JSON`, ele é convertido como um objeto e não como um array. Por isso, mesmo o valor de `items` sendo um array, a interpretação dele é como um objeto.

Ao adicionar o objeto item dentro de um novo array, sem informar índice, por padrão, ele utilizará o índice zero (0), o que o tornará um array indexado. Arrays indexados, por sua vez, são mantidos como arrays no `JSON`.

**Nota:** O array foi simplificado para demonstrar apenas o problema

**Update**

Há mais uma questão no seu código. Você está convertendo o `array` para `JSON`, mas está enviando o array para a `API`:

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

No código abaixo, deveria ser `$data_string`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Envie no cabeçalho, também, o tipo de dados e o tamanho:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($user.':'.$pass),                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($data_string)
));
```

Comment: fiz aqui porém o erro continua, fiz dessa maneira:"items" => array(
                           array(
                               "description"=>"carro",
                               "quantity"=> 1,
                               "price_cents"=>150000


                                ),
                           array(
                               "description"=>"moto",
                               "quantity"=> 3,
                               "price_cents"=>150000


                           )

                )         converti para json e tbm não deu.

Comment: @user9806474 eu atualizei a resposta com outros pontos que você deve mudar

Comment: Deu certo, muito abrigado cara!! me salvou no estagio!!

Comment: @user9806474 marque a resposta como correta e, se possível, +1